# Microsoft Edge store denied my addon (a search tool). Need explaination

Tags: microsoft-edge, search-engine, browser-addons

I was trying to submit my addon ([source code](https://github.com/garywill/bigSearch)) about search engines to Edge addon store.

I got denied. The reason they gave me is:

> Critical Validations     1   failure(s)
>
> Product Policies
> 1.1.8  Distinct Function & Value; Accurate Representation
>
> The extension inappropriately replaces the default search engine with that of a third party. You must be the owner or employee of the third party to do so.

**I have questions about**

**1.**

> The extension inappropriately replaces the default search engine

My addon doesn't change any browser settings. Won't change default search engine. It just gives user more options to use other search engines.

**2.**

> You must be the owner or employee of the third party to do so

My addon provides convinience for user to use Google/Bing/Duckduckgo etc. multiple search engines.

Of cource I don't own Google/Bing/Duckduckgo. My addon provide convinience for your browser users. And it provides way to let user add any search engines they like as shortcut (user using JSON).

Why Edge denies such a tool? It's a tool that sends GET/POST requests, which is what browsers do when user want to search online.

Comment: I agree with Vincent Bitter's answer. If you still have questions about the review result of your extension, I suggest that you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/contact-extensions-team#request-help-for-any-issues-or-submit-feedback) to submit your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the full policy at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/store-policies/developer-policies

It states:

> Your extension must not, without appropriate user consent, alter, or appear to alter, browser functionality or settings including, but not limited to: the address bar search provider...

Apparently, Microsoft thinks changing a dropdown is not an appropriate user consent, or it is not clearly mentioned in the app description as required:

> Any alteration to the browser settings should be explicitly documented in the description of your extension.

Also, the policy clearly states you need to be the owner or employee of the search engine:

> Your extension may only revise key settings to replace a Microsoft webpage or service with that of a third-party (such as require use of a third-party search engine or set the home page to a third-party web property) if you are employed by or otherwise associated with such third-party.

I think they don’t want anyone else than the owner to build extensions in name of third parties to avoid trademark issues or possible extensions with duplicate functionalities.

I understand this is disappointing after all your hard work, but that’s the risk of building extensions I’m afraid.